# C# mvc DropDownList validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a couple of DropDownLists and I want to make them required. I am not using strongly typed views and view models. Both are filled from a database.

```
// in controller 
while (reader.Read())
{
    emps.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
       Text = reader["CODE"].ToString(),
       Selected = Request["vEmps"] == reader["CODE"].ToString() ? true : false
    });
}

// in view
@Html.DropDownList("vEmps", null, new { @id = "Code" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make drop down items required. You can only make the drop down list.
Try using [this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper.dropdownlist?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2#System_Web_WebPages_Html_HtmlHelper_DropDownList_System_String_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Web_WebPages_Html_SelectListItem__System_Object_System_Object_) and populate the attributes parameters with the "required","required"

Use something like:

```
@Html.DropDownList("vEmps",
  new SelectListItem[] {
    new SelectListItem("Employee1", "Employee1"),
    new SelectListItem("Employee2", "Employee2"),
    new SelectListItem("Employee3", "Employee3"),
    new SelectListItem("Employee4", "Employee4") },
  null,
  new { required = "required" })
```

It will Render the html like:

```
<select id="vEmps" name="vEmps" required="required">
<option value="Employee1">Employee1</option>
<option value="Employee2">Employee2</option>
<option value="Employee3">Employee3</option>
<option value="Employee4">Employee4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of adding attributes to a SelectListItem?

Comment: I updated my answer with the example. It formatted nicer than doing it in the comment.